# Digital signature integration in asp.net core

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, digital-signature, adobe-sign

I have integrated digital signature on a pdf using asp.net core and adobe esign API. So I can sign the agreement via email or sign via the embed widget in my website.

But actually, I want show a simple agreement (this is just text) and sign it in a customizable way in my web site.

How can I achieve this? Below I have provide the UI of my web page.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]